# How safe is a MongoDB full collection scan?

Tags: database, mongodb, performance, concurrency

Let’s say I have a large MongoDB collection. Every night, I want to run a query on it, filtering by a field that is not currently indexed. I don’t care how long the query takes (I’ll be monitoring it, and if it starts taking longer than a couple hours, I’ll reconsider). So I’d prefer not to build an index just for this query, as every index brings some operational overhead.

However, what I **do** care about is that this full scan doesn’t adversely affect any other commands on this MongoDB instance. It must not lock anything, make my disk I/O grind to a halt, etc.

If this were a separate Linux process, I might run it under `nice` and/or `ionice`.

Can I / Do I need to take any similar precautions here with MongoDB? Or are full scans typically safe by default? If “it depends”, on what?

Assume a typical Linux system running on typical server hardware.

Comment: It depends on the size of your working set, how big your RAM, how fast your disk, and how big your WiredTiger cache. Basically doing a collection scan will replace the content of the cache with the collscaned collection. If this is not your typical working set, then when you need the cluster to do work it will need to reload the working set from disk again. This could appear as slow queries, depending on how fast your disk can load the RAM. Other than that, it should not lock anything. This should be bottlenecked by disk performance more than anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on a combination of:

- **Your disk speed**: since typically a collection scan will need to do large fetches from disk (especially on a large collection), a faster disk would be more beneficial overall.
- **The size of your WiredTiger cache and the size of your overall RAM**: larger memory size typically permits you to have more things in memory and a larger WiredTiger cache, which is beneficial to most workloads (not only on collection scans).
- **The size of your typical working set**: the larger your typical working set, the more time it would take to repopulate the cache after the collection scan work is finished.

WiredTiger needs to load documents into its cache before it can manipulate them or return them as a query reply. This means that doing a collection scan will replace the content of the cache with the collscaned collection.

If the collscaned collection does not form your typical working set, then when you need the cluster to do work, it will need to reload the working set from disk again. This could appear as slow queries while the cache is repopulated, depending on how fast your disk can satisfy the request.

In other words, the collection scan vs. the typical working set would constitute as a change in work pattern, so some delay during the change in workload should be expected.

Other than that, WiredTiger is an optimistic concurrency storage engine, where it does not really lock anything other than during global metadata changes (drop collection, drop database, etc.). It transparently retries writes in the event of conflict, and it doesn't block readers due to MVCC. The work you described should be bottlenecked by disk performance more than anything.

**Note**: the optimistic concurrency in WiredTiger described above is only true for the primary node of a replica set. Secondaries block reads during periods of oplog apply, since during oplog apply there could be moments when the database is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1):

#### When is it a good idea to read from secondaries?

If you are not using a sharded cluster but you are using a replica set and you are fine with stale data, you could [read from a secondary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/):

```
db.collection.find({ ... }).readPref("secondary");
```

This is a great idea when running analytics/reports queries, as they are usually resource-intensive and long-running, so you would affect the reads and writes coming from the application if those are run on the primary.

#### When is it a bad idea to read from secondaries?

[From the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-balancer-administration/):

> The MongoDB balancer is a background process that monitors the number of chunks on each shard. When the number of chunks on a given shard reaches specific migration thresholds, the balancer attempts to automatically migrate chunks between shards and reach an equal number of chunks per shard.

The problem with reading from secondaries on sharded clusters is that you might get duplicate, orphaned, stale or missing data when this process is running or has been aborted.

See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5931.

However, it looks that this has been fixed in `3.6`, but I can't find any mention of this issue neither in the [release notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6/) nor in the [changelog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.6-changelog/).

If you are using MongoDB `3.6` or higher you might just give this solution a try or otherwise you could wait to see if someone else can shed some light on this.

#### When is it a good idea to have indexes on secondaries?

You might also consider creating indexes to speed up that query on a single secondary, which should not be allowed to become a primary by:

- [Setting `priority = 0`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-priority-0-member/), so that this node can't become the primary, as otherwise your application's performance, especially write performance, will drastically decrease due to the extra overhead to update your analytics/reporting indexes on this node.
- [Using a hidden node](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-hidden-member/), which prevents connections to the replica set from routing reads to this particular node, even if they specify a read preference of `secondary`.

  However, if you are using a 3 members replica set, having one hidden node means that if the other 2 go down, the third (hidden) one will not be taking care of [client reads](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-hidden-member/#read-operations). You might compensate this having 5 members (1 hidden) instead of 3.
- [Using a delayed node](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-delayed-member/), which [should also have `priority = 0` and be hidden](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-delayed-member/#requirements).
- [Using replica set tag sets](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-replica-set-tag-sets/) and [read preference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Mongo.setReadPref/) to route analytics/reporting queries to specific nodes, which would have `priority = 0` but would not be hidden, so they can take reads from clients. This also offers some [additional flexibility](https://devops.com/mongodb-replication-pro-tips/#benefitsandconsiderations) that you don't have with the other approaches.

Comment: I am using a sharded cluster of replica sets. Why doesn’t your recommendation apply to one?

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov Please, take a look at the updated answer, I have elaborated a bit on the previous suggestions and explained why reading from secondaries on a sharded cluster is (?) or was (?) a bad idea. In short, the sharding balancer might make your reads on secondaries return incorrect data, but that issue appears as `Fixed` in MongodDB's JIRA, so I'm not sure that's still the case. Anyway, they still mention that should be avoided in MongoDB's M201 course. I will tag someone that might be able to clarify this.

Comment: Hi @stennie, apologies for the direct approach, but I think you might be able to give us an update on https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5931 as it is not clear to my what the status is in MongoDB `3.6` or higher regarding reading from secondaries on sharded clusters. Thanks a lot (: